# MySQL errors using UNION ALL with subqueries and variables

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery, union-all

I have a table **currency_lkp** and a table associate_data
The associate_data has these columns - **currency, invoice_total** and status **(Unpaid or Paid or WaitingI)**
I can succesfully link the tables with the top half of this query ([see MySQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4b5bb/13/0))  and provide a total for each currency.

I can also provide a correct total for each status converted into USD (see the bottom half of the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4b5bb/13/0)   Which produces one line

When I use **UNION ALL** between the two halves it produces a result but very strange figures in the middle three columns but the correct result in the 4th column and the final row of that column.

I think the query is OK but could be neater if it was possible to use variables with the sub-queries.  Any ideas on what is going wrong or how to improve the elegance will be greatly appreciated - thank you

**To create a sample db:**  (MySQL query below this)

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `currency_lkp` (
  `currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `currency_label` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `currency_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `exchange_rate_USD` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`currency_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `currency_lkp` (`currency_id`, `currency`, 
`currency_label`, `currency_description`, `exchange_rate_USD`)
VALUES
(1, 'GBP', '&pound;', 'Great British Pound (Sterling)', 0.75),
(2, 'Euro', '&euro;', 'Euro currency for the Euro Zone', 0.85),
(3, 'USD', '$', 'United States Dollars', 1),
(4, 'CLP', '$', 'Chilean Pesos', 639.85),
(5, 'INR', '&#8377', 'Indian Rupees', 64.8);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `associate_data` (`associate_data_id`
int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`currency` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
`status` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
`invoice_total` float,
 PRIMARY KEY (`associate_data_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
  
INSERT INTO `associate_data` (`associate_data_id`, `currency`, 
`status`, `invoice_total`)
 VALUES
(1, 'GBP', 'Paid', 200),
(2, 'GBP', 'Unpaid', 300),
(3, 'Euro', 'Paid', 1000),
(4, 'Euro', 'Unpaid', 2000),
(5, 'USD', 'Paid', 1200),
(6, 'USD', 'Unpaid', 1400),
(7, 'GBP', 'WaitingInvoice', 400),
(8, 'Euro', 'WaitingInvoice', 1300),
(9, 'USD', 'WaitingInvoice', 2300),
(10, 'CLP', 'Paid', 100200),
(11, 'CLP', 'Unpaid', 110400),
(12, 'CLP', 'WaitingInvoice', 11200);

MySQL Query in full:
`
(
SELECT cl.currency,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad2
WHERE ad2.currency = cl.currency  AND ad2.status = 'Paid') AS Paid,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad3
WHERE ad3.currency = cl.currency  AND ad3.status = 'Unpaid') AS Unpaid,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad4
WHERE ad4.currency = cl.currency  AND ad4.status = 'WaitingInvoice') AS WaitingInvoice,
(SELECT IFNULL(Unpaid,0) + IFNULL(WaitingInvoice, 0)) AS TotalToPay
FROM currency_lkp cl
)

UNION ALL

(
SELECT 'Total in USD',

FORMAT(
SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad5
WHERE ad5.currency = clu.currency AND (ad5.status = 'Paid'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
,0) AS TotalUSDPaid,

FORMAT(
SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'Unpaid'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
,0) AS TotalUSDUnpaid,

FORMAT(
SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'WaitingInvoice'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
,0) AS TotalUSDWaitingInvoice,

FORMAT(
SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'WaitingInvoice' OR ad6.status = 'Unpaid'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
,0) AS TotalUSDToPay
FROM currency_lkp clu
)`
```

Comment: Please include the query directly in your question.  Links can (and do) break over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can radically simplify your query (and improve efficiency) by using "conditional aggregates" (*a case expression INSIDE the aggregate function*) like this:

```
select
      cu.currency
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'Paid' then invoice_total end) as Paid
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'Unpaid' then invoice_total end) as Unpaid
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'WaitingInvoice' then invoice_total end) as WaitingInvoice_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'Paid' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as Paid_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'Unpaid' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as Unpaid_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'WaitingInvoice' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as WaitingInvoice_USD  
FROM associate_data ad
inner join currency_lkp cu ON ad.currency = cu.currency
group by
      cu.currency
union all
select
      'Total'
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'Paid' then invoice_total end) as Paid
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'Unpaid' then invoice_total end) as Unpaid
    , sum(case when ad.status = 'WaitingInvoice' then invoice_total end) as WaitingInvoice_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'Paid' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as Paid_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'Unpaid' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as Unpaid_USD
    , FORMAT(sum(case when ad.status = 'WaitingInvoice' then invoice_total/cu.exchange_rate_USD end),0) as WaitingInvoice_USD  
FROM associate_data ad
inner join currency_lkp cu ON ad.currency = cu.currency
;
```

That query produces the following result:

```
| currency |   Paid | Unpaid | WaitingInvoice_USD | Paid_USD | Unpaid_USD | WaitingInvoice_USD |
|----------|--------|--------|--------------------|----------|------------|--------------------|
|      CLP | 100200 | 110400 |              11200 |      157 |        173 |                 18 |
|     Euro |   1000 |   2000 |               1300 |    1,176 |      2,353 |              1,529 |
|      GBP |    200 |    300 |                400 |      267 |        400 |                533 |
|      USD |   1200 |   1400 |               2300 |    1,200 |      1,400 |              2,300 |
|    Total | 102600 | 114100 |              15200 |    2,800 |      4,325 |              4,380 |
```

see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4b5bb/36

The reason for the gobbledygook in some columns of your former query was attempting to union numbers and formatted (text) data in the same columns. Remove the `format(  ,0)`

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4b5bb/37

```
(
SELECT cl.currency,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad2
WHERE ad2.currency = cl.currency  AND ad2.status = 'Paid') AS Paid,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad3
WHERE ad3.currency = cl.currency  AND ad3.status = 'Unpaid') AS Unpaid,
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad4
WHERE ad4.currency = cl.currency  AND ad4.status = 'WaitingInvoice') AS WaitingInvoice,
(SELECT IFNULL(Unpaid,0) + IFNULL(WaitingInvoice, 0)) AS TotalToPay
FROM currency_lkp cl
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 'Total in USD',


SUM(IFNULL(
(
  SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad5
WHERE ad5.currency = clu.currency AND (ad5.status = 'Paid')
),0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD) 
  AS TotalUSDPaid,


SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'Unpaid'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
 AS TotalUSDUnpaid,


SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'WaitingInvoice'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
 AS TotalUSDWaitingInvoice,


SUM(IFNULL(
(SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM associate_data ad6
WHERE ad6.currency = clu.currency AND (ad6.status = 'WaitingInvoice' OR ad6.status = 'Unpaid'))
,0.1)/clu.exchange_rate_USD)
 AS TotalUSDToPay
FROM currency_lkp clu
)
```

and the result of that query is:

```
|     currency |               Paid |           Unpaid |    WaitingInvoice |        TotalToPay |
|--------------|--------------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          GBP |                200 |              300 |               400 |               700 |
|         Euro |               1000 |             2000 |              1300 |              3300 |
|          USD |               1200 |             1400 |              2300 |              3700 |
|          CLP |             100200 |           110400 |             11200 |            121600 |
|          INR |             (null) |           (null) |            (null) |                 0 |
| Total in USD | 2799.7379740260294 | 4325.48309943104 | 4380.250701542091 | 8705.732257763328 |
```

NB: I have not attempted to correct any query arithmetic, but clearly one of them is wrong

Comment: Thank you for really helpful answer.  Which I have implemented but still with an error.  For example I get data such as "31323739382e3530".

Comment: Thank you for really helpful answer.  Which I have implemented but still with an error.  For example I get data such as "31323739382e3530".  First I thought it might be that associate_data is a View.  So I tried Select on the source table with the same result.  Then I thought perhaps it is that datatype is float.  So I created column with datatype Decimal - all with the same result.  The updated sub-query which you set out with the Format does however work - including FORMAT(SUM(IFNULL(xxx),0)
 in the last (total) row.   Again thank you and further insight greatly appreciated

Comment: Apologies - now I understand your answer properly - it is the mix in UNION ALL of FORMAT and the absence of FORMAT - I have now made all lines use the FORMAT statement and voilà - all is working.  Many many thanks

Comment: Actually I  wanted you to consider use the top query style instead of your original, but in any case you should format consistently and as late as possible.

Comment: Thank you  - yes I have used the query style you suggested - much cleaner than the sub-queries.  This partly started with me thinking that using variables (Select ... into) might be the most elegant solution as both sides of the Union statement start with the same query - might this be possible?